# declare char variable in c++, why need to add 1 for declare the array size

Tags: c++, arrays, c, char, declare

There is a saying when we declare char variable.

We should declare like this -> `char ArrayName[Maximum_C-String_Size+1];`

For example:

```
char arr[4+1] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

but
`arr[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}` is also work

why need to add 1?
thanks!

Comment: You need to add 1 if you plan to treat `arr` as a NUL-terminated string. The extra element is to store, well, the NUL terminator.

Comment: End string of chars symbol '\n'

Comment: If you've found a tutorial or book that uses `arr[4+1]`, stop using that tutorial or book and find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this, unless you are defining something that will be used as a null-terminated string.

```
// these two definitions are equivalent
char a[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
char b[5] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0' };
```

If you only want an array with 4 char values in it, and you won't be using that with anything that expects to find a string terminator, then you don't need to add an extra element.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re storing a C-style *string* in an array, then you need an extra element for the string terminator.

Unlike C++, C does not have a unique string data type.  In C, a string is simply a sequence of character values including a zero-valued terminator.  The string `"foo"` is represented as the sequence `{'f','o','o',0}`.  That terminator is how the various string handling functions know where the string ends.  The terminator is not a printable character and is not counted towards the length of the string (`strlen("foo")` returns 3, not 4), however you need to set aside space to store it.  So, if you need to store a string that’s N characters long, then  the array in which it is stored needs to be at least N+1 elements wide to account for the terminator.

However, if you’re storing a sequence that’s not meant to be treated as a *string* (you don’t intend to print it or manipulate it with the string library functions), then you don’t need to set aside the extra element.